# No call stack in VS2010 debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've got an app that loads a DLL, and subsequently crashes. I modified the IDE's working directory to be the solution build directory, so that I could run the debugger on the built DLL which is built from another project in this solution. When the app gets an access violation, I can see the current function, but nothing of the call stack, and none of the locals will evaluate. I've checked and there are debugger symbols in this directory, and it was all built in debug mode. What could be the cause of the debugger failing?

Edit: If I place a breakpoint, then the debugger works fine- although, of course, this still doesn't tell me why the app is crashing, but I do get a call stack and all the symbols will happily evaluate.

Comment: Is it [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/24/show-external-code-vstipdebug0031.aspx) "Show External Code" setting?

Comment: @DOK: No, that's for managed applications and I'm using a native application.

Comment: I found that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You might get some other ideas there.

Comment: Can you set the debug options to break on all first-chance exceptions?

Comment: Are you loading Windows' symbol files as well?  That makes the call stack evaluate better.

Comment: @Chris O: There are no Windows functions in the call stack at this specific point. I verified this using the breakpoint, which works exactly as expected.

Comment: I've found that with VS2008 and VS2010, you almost always need the Windows' symbol files in order to get useful call stacks, otherwise you'll get missing/invalid/bogus call stacks being displayed until enough window symbol files are loaded.

Comment: There is *no call stack whatsoever*?  Or is there a call stack with a bunch of machine addresses and such?

Comment: @John Dibling: There was the current function, one machine address above (which I verified was the address I attempted to call), and one machine address below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the debugger work when it hits a break point and fails when you break after an access violation in native code usually a sign that the access violation is preceded or accompanied by a corruption of the stack.

The debugger depends on certain values in the stack being properly set in order for it to both build the correct stack view and access local variables.  If this data is corrupted it can prevent both locals from being displayed and an accurate picture of the stack from being generated.

In the case where you hit the break point before the access violation the stack is still in tact and the debugger can freely view information.

Comment: Interesting theory. Now I just have to hunt down why I'm throwing an access violation *and* blowing my stack on a perfectly good function call.

Comment: OK. I found the cause of the actual problem (I called FreeLibrary() on the DLL before trying to call the function I got from it), but still don't see why it would kill the debugger.

Comment: @DeadMG at the point you called `FreeLibrary` the function pointer was essentially pointing to random memory which you then invoked as a function. That likely resulted in the corruption of the stack